# htaccess mod_rewrite rule to just remove a question mark in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a condition/rule to rewrite any urls

www.mywebsite.com/?admin/***

to

www.mywebsite.com/admin/***

so ?admin to admin

AKA remove that question mark from the URL (only when followed by admin obviously).
I know it's a weird URL but that's a long story, all I need is to rewrite all admin URLs so that the query question mark is removed.

Thank you

Comment: $LongStory = " [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ";

Comment: Regex ^(.+)\?admin(.*)$ to $1admin$2

Comment: Yes it's a hack but I don;t have time to get to the bottom of this and just a rewrite will solve my problem for now. We will get to the full fix later. Thanks

Comment: @iKiWiXz thanks but it's not doing anything

Comment: I gave you a regex that you have to put in mod_rewrite. I can't guarantie that it will work tho

Comment: Thanks appreciate but it didn't do it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the rule below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?(admin[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I need it to be only when the question mark is followed by admin because we still use queries on the URL

Comment: that's working but not keeping whatever is after /admin/ ie /?admin/login is being redirect to /admin when it should go to /admin/login